# with webpack create vendor and app bundles and load with requirejs

Tags: javascript, webpack, requirejs

Is it possible to create multiple bundles ('vendor','app') with webpack and load them with requirejs? In this example i can create bundles, but when I try to load them with requirejs returned module is undefined.

**webpack.config.js:**

```
module.exports = {    
    entry: {
        app: './app.js',
        //vendor: ['bootstrap', 'popper.js','jquery','underscore']
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
      filename: '[name].bundle.js',      
      libraryTarget: 'umd',
      globalObject: 'this',
      umdNamedDefine: true,
      pathinfo: true
    },
    resolve: {        
        alias: {
            popper: "popper.js",    
        },
        extensions: ['.js'] // File types
    },    

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            },            
        ]
    },


    plugins: [
    ],    

    optimization: {
        namedModules: true,
        splitChunks: {
            chunks: "async",
            cacheGroups: {
                app: {
                    reuseExistingChunk: true,
                },
                vendor: {
                    test: /node_modules/,
                    chunks: 'all',
                    name: 'vendor',
                },
            }
        },        
    },
};
```

**index.js**

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        'vendor': './dist/vendor.bundle',
        requireLib: 'require',
        'all_app': './dist/app.bundle'
    },
    bundles: {
        'all_app': ['app','./menuTooltips','./NavMenu'],
        'vendor': [/*'bootstrap',*/ 'jquery' /*, 'underscore',*/ /*, 'popper'*/ ],
    },
    nodeIdCompat: true,
});

define(['require', './app'], function (require, app) {
    console.log(app); // app is undefined!!!!
    app.Init();
});
```

**index.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./lib/require.min.js" data-main="index.js"></script>
```

When index.js requires 'app' dist/app.bundle is loaded (network tab shows that), but returned app object is undefined.

Answer (score -2):

App bundle can be loaded without requirejs (vendor bundle must be included first):

**index.html**

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./dist/vendor.bundle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./dist/app.bundle.js"></script>
    <script>
        window.onload = function () {
            MyLib.app.Init();
        };
    </script>
```

**webpack.config.js**

> added line 'library':

```
  output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
      filename: '[name].bundle.js',                
      libraryTarget: 'umd',
      globalObject: 'this',
      umdNamedDefine: true,
      library: ["MyLib", "[name]"]
    },
```